# I want embed a webpage in powerpoint

Tags: vba, embed, powerpoint, html

I want embed a just simple webpage in Powerpoint. The page must automatically load from the given URL when the slideshow starts. No text-box no click-button.

I've insert a Web Browser element from the developer tab.
The code that i used is:

```
Sub Main()
WebBrowser1.Navigate ("www.google.com")
End Sub
```

Powerpoint shows a file explorer in the slideshow.

What did i wrong?

Cheers.

Comment: Try with "http://" in front of the web address.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found it

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange()
Dim i As Integer
i = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.CurrentShowPosition
If i <> 1 Then Exit Sub
WebBrowser1.Navigate ("www.google.com")
End Sub
```